# Перенос базы с 5.5.9 на 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет! 
Народ подскажите почему при переносе базы данных с версии mysql 5.5.9 на версию 5.6
Некоторые функции перестают работать.
Переносил базу используя navicat так:
Делаю Dump Sql в версии 5.5.9 , далее создаю базу в 5.6 и полученный файл .sql переношу в неё с помощью функции Execute Sql.
Так можно переносить или это работает нормально при одинfковой версии mysql?
Мб в размере базы дело уже не знаю что подумать, перенос делал раз 10...

Примечание: две базы, одна чуть больше 500мб.

Comment: Для той же версии работает бессбойно. А вот при изменении версии следует тщательно изучать все изменения. *Некоторые функции перестают работать.* Начать с пересоздания вручную и тестирования - в т.ч. на краевые значения. Ну и просто поизучать тексты в дампе, индивидуально по каждой функции.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ну я так и предполагал в принципе, вы подтверди ли мои опасения по поводу ручной правки, просто 500мб думал может есть ещё варианты.

Comment: *просто 500мб* Сделайте дамп только структуры, без данных. Получится на-а-амного меньше...